# Como incluir una clase dentro de otra en PHP utilizando FPDF

Tags: php, html, web, pdf, fpdf

ojalá me puedan apoyar, soy principiante, estoy trabajando con PHP y FPDF, actualmente tengo un documento llamado index.php con el siguiente código:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Constantes.php');
require_once(RUTA_FPDF_PHP);
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddFont('Calibri', '', 'Calibri.php');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Calibri', '', 8);
$pdf->MultiCell(50, 5, utf8_decode("Hola mundo"), 1, 'C', FALSE);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

y en otro archivo denominado ellipse.php (lo obtuve de internet, dibuja elipses y circulos en PDF) el siguiente código:

```
<?php

require_once 'Constantes.php';
require_once(RAIZ . '/PDF/fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF_Ellipse extends FPDF
{
function Circle($x, $y, $r, $style='D')
{
    $this->Ellipse($x, $y, $r, $r, $style);
}

function Ellipse($x, $y, $rx, $ry, $style='D')
{
    if($style=='F')
        $op='f';
    elseif($style=='FD' || $style=='DF')
        $op='B';
    else
        $op='S';
    $lx=4/3*(M_SQRT2-1)*$rx;
    $ly=4/3*(M_SQRT2-1)*$ry;
    $k=$this->k;
    $h=$this->h;
    $this->_out(sprintf('%.2F %.2F m %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F c', 
        ($x+$rx)*$k, ($h-$y)*$k, 
        ($x+$rx)*$k, ($h-($y-$ly))*$k, 
        ($x+$lx)*$k, ($h-($y-$ry))*$k, 
        $x*$k, ($h-($y-$ry))*$k));
    $this->_out(sprintf('%.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F c', 
        ($x-$lx)*$k, ($h-($y-$ry))*$k, 
        ($x-$rx)*$k, ($h-($y-$ly))*$k, 
        ($x-$rx)*$k, ($h-$y)*$k));
    $this->_out(sprintf('%.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F c', 
        ($x-$rx)*$k, ($h-($y+$ly))*$k, 
        ($x-$lx)*$k, ($h-($y+$ry))*$k, 
        $x*$k, ($h-($y+$ry))*$k));
    $this->_out(sprintf('%.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F c %s', 
        ($x+$lx)*$k, ($h-($y+$ry))*$k, 
        ($x+$rx)*$k, ($h-($y+$ly))*$k, 
        ($x+$rx)*$k, ($h-$y)*$k, 
        $op));
}
}
?>
```

ya probé el codigo de ellipse.php y funciona a la perfección, lo que no sé es cómo instanciar un nuevo objeto de la clase PDF_Ellipse para poder incluirlo en mi index.php, necesito hacer varios circulos en index.php, pero no sé como iniciar la clase, ni como incluirlo a mi index.php. Espero me puedan ayudar.

De antemano muchas gracias a todos.

P.D. Trabajo con Windows 7 y PHP 7.

Comment: Creo que ya le estoy entendiendo, corrijanme si estoy mal,  al crear la class PDF_Ellipse, estoy tomando todas las funciones de la Class FPDF y le estoy agregando nuevas funciones, por lo que de ahora en adelante ya no debo llamar a FPDF, si no a PDF_Ellipse, el cual incluirá toda la class FPDF y además agregará las funciones Circle y Ellipse. Por favor diganme si estoy en lo correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Has probado algo como?

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Constantes.php');
require_once(RUTA_FPDF_PHP);
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddFont('Calibri', '', 'Calibri.php');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Calibri', '', 8);
$pdf->MultiCell(50, 5, utf8_decode("Hola mundo"), 1, 'C', FALSE);
$pdf->Ellipse(100,50,30,20);//Esta es la línea que dibujará tu elipse
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: Si. Lo probé, pero acabó de caer en el entendido que en sí ya no debo inicializar la class FPDF, sino más bien inicializar la class PDF_Eclipse que es una clase extendida de FPDF, y ahí si puedo agregar el circulo sin problema.

Comment: Y porque no simplemente copias la funcion Ellipse a la clase donde estás creando el PDF y la mandas a llamar desde ahí mismo o mueves toda la lógica a la clase PDF_Ellipse y desde tu documento padre la haces funcionar?